# Directives are not listening for $watch when I change any select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created this directives in Angular:

```
app.directive('country', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: "C",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $http.get(Routing.generate('countries')).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.message) {
                        scope.message = data.message;
                    } else {
                        scope.countries = data.entities;
                    }
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (status == '500') {
                        scope.message = "No hay conexión con el servidor.";
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

app.directive('state', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: "C",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.trigger, function(selectedType) {
                    if (eval('scope.' + attrs.trigger) !== undefined) {
                        states = eval('scope.' + attrs.statetrigger);
                        states = {};

                        $http.get(Routing.generate('states') + '/' + eval('scope.' + attrs.trigger).iso_country).success(function(data) {
                            if (data.message) {
                                scope.message = data.message;
                            } else {
                                scope.states = data.entities;
                            }
                        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            if (status == '500') {
                                scope.message = "No hay conexión con el servidor.";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And this is the HTML code related:

```
<select class="country"
        ng-model = "country"
        ng-options = "country.iso_country as country.name for country in countries"
        tooltip = ""
        tooltip-trigger = "focus"
        tooltip-placement = "right"
        wv-cur = ""
        wv-err = "Error!"
        wv-req = "The value you selected is not a valid choice"
        type = "text">
    <option value="">{{ "Select country" | trans }}</option>
</select>

<select class="state"
        ng-model = "state"
        ng-disabled = "!states"
        ng-options = "state.iso as state.name for state in states"
        tooltip-trigger = "focus"
        tooltip-placement = "right"
        wv-cur = ""
        wv-err = "Error!"
        wv-req = "The value you selected is not a valid choice"
        type = "text"
        trigger = "country">
    <option value="">{{ "Select state" | trans }}</option>
</select>
```

The idea behind this is: when I change any country I should populate the `states` with new values coming from second directive but `$watch` is not listening since second select never is populated, where is my mistake?

Comment: scope is passed to the link function, what are you trying to do with the injection of `$scope`? I'm not sure it makes sense

Comment: @hassassin I'll rewrite my question, forget about a scope, give me some minutes to share my problem/doubt

Comment: I am quite sure that a small self-contained plunker or jsfiddle sample of your code would trigger lots of useful answers.

Comment: @ŽeljkoSzep the problem is data is generated through PHP in server side for that reason I don't wrote a Plunker

Comment: You could replace the PHP call with a $http request for a JSON file or just provide the data via an javascript array.

Comment: Here is the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1dcC7H4qyENRvU8Cjpw3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope` is a special injection object that is only avialable to Controllers.

You can reference `$rootScope`, but that is ill-advised unless you are building a service or directive that is pretty universal/global.

**UPDATE:**

You are trying to use a raw `eval` for something that is specific to Angular. You really want to use the [`$parse` function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24parse) in order to extract values from `scope`

```
var accessor = $parse(attrs.trigger);
var value = accessor(scope);
```

**Update 2:**

I have recreated a ver [slimmed down version of your code using jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/CT7BJ) and have found it works just fine. You will have to step through your code to figure out what the problem is because there is clearly an error that we can't see.

Comment: See my edition, I solve the problem so I change the main question, sorry for that one

Comment: @ReynierPM - Do you know if the `$watch` actually isn't firing? Can you add a console.log to see if it at least makes it that far?

Comment: I'm getting this error '$parse is not defined' related to `$parse`, should I inject this or why the error? And not `$watch` is not fire since I have a `console.log()` inside that watch and it's not working

Comment: @ReynierPM - Yes you need to inject `$parse` as it is one of the Angular services. And I think you meant to trigger on **"countries"** instead of **"country"**

Comment: So I should change the `ng-model` on the HTML code or what I need to change?

Comment: @ReynierPM - I've added a jsFiddle to further show this approach

Comment: I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1dcC7H4qyENRvU8Cjpw3) with my code, could you take a look? I see yours and it works but mine doesn't and I can't find where my error is

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of the Scope in Angular.

The Scope is the link between the DOM-Tree and JS. So a Scope is always valid inside an "Area" of the DOM (aka a Element and its Child-Nodes). So what Angular needs to know is WHERE you wanna Apply that Scope. In a directive, this is obivously the directives template or more exact: The Element on which the directive is defined. Therefore, inside your linking function, you have the `scope`-Variable.

The `$scope`-Variable on the other hand is the Scope of a Controller - which´s Scope you explicitly define by setting the Controller inside the Dom with the `ng-controller`.

Long story short: Injecting a `$scope` inside a directive doesnt make any sense, since Angular wouldnt know which DOM it belongs to.

If you want to access a Controllers `$scope` from within a Directive, you could either try `scope.$parent` or use a Service to Share the Data.